# Get likes count on login required pages

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I need get likes of different facebooks pages, but one of these requires login.
The page is https://www.facebook.com/pages/Notitrece/112045468823315 and it can not be seen without login with your facebook account.
To the rest of pages I've used the graph method (http://graph.facebook.com/pageID) to get likes info.

For the page in question, I tested with app FB and FQL, but I've had no luck.

Comment: The page link is not working.

Comment: yes, that page works. You have to be logged into facebook to see it. Test it. Thank you.

Comment: I'm logged in, and I get redirected to my newsfeed. Sure the page is published?

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/pages/Notitrece/112045468823315 is published. I dont understend.